# Mean and standard error of raster data

Tags: r

I have a 30-meter raster data of an area of carbon stock. I want to calculate mean and standard error using R. It can be calculated easily but the SE is very very low, I am sure it is underestimation.

Is there another way to do it in R?

If it was a point sampled data, kriging would have been an option, but this image contains entire area.

```
> inv3001<-raster("E:/chap2/inv_30m_01.tif")
> Minv3001<-cellStats(inv3001, stat='mean', na.rm=TRUE, asSample=TRUE)
Mean:207
> Sinv3001<-cellStats(inv3001, stat='sd', na.rm=TRUE, asSample=TRUE)
Stdev:87
> Erinv3001<-Sinv3001/sqrt(length(inv3001))
Std Error:0.02
```

Comment: What makes you think its too small? If I reverse your calculation for `Erinv3001` I get that the length of `inv3001` is (87/0.02)^2 = 19 million. If you estimate the mean of 19 million things you'll surely get a really good estimate of that mean (for any "sensibly distributed" values). What does a histogram of the values look like?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about ArcMap then please do that in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SE seems reasonable. Reversing your calculation tells us that you have

```
> (87/0.02)^2
[1] 18922500
```

about 19 million pixels. If I create 19 million values from a normal distribution from the estimates you give me, I get a similar result for the SE of the mean estimate:

```
> v = rnorm(19000000, mean=207, sd=87)
> mean(v)
[1] 207.0138
> sd(v)
[1] 86.99965
> sd(v)/sqrt(length(v))
[1] 0.01995909
```

For a smaller data set, say 1000 points, the SE on the mean estimate is much larger:

```
> z = rnorm(1000, mean=207, sd=87)
> sd(z)/sqrt(length(z))
[1] 2.707512
```